# Identify book or long story in which a young Rudyard Kipling appears out of his time

Tags: story-identification, novel

In this book (or possibly long story) from maybe 20 years ago, time is fractured or jumbled.  Characters from many different times mysteriously appear.  The events may be set in the vicinity of Afghanistan, but I am not sure.

The main character (MC) is from our era.  Another main character is a **young** **Rudyard Kipling**, who has just started to write.  There is also a population of homo erectus. Several individuals from different eras, including the MC, band together for survival in the chaos that results from the fracturing of time.

Towards the end, Kipling is wounded and dying.  He mourns that he will never write all that is seething in his brain, ready to be written.  The main character (MC) assures him that in the MC's time, Kipling was a great and beloved writer.

This is all I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite 20 years ago, but could it be the 2003 novel *Time's Eye* by Arthur C Clarke and Stephen Baxter? From [Wikipedia's long summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%27s_Eye_(novel)) (emphasis mine):

> The story starts from two hominids, known as 'Seeker', a mother, and her infant daughter 'Grasper'. They are **somewhere in the genetic chain between humans and apes** [*Rand note: maybe these are your homo erectus?*]. As they walked on the tranquil Earth 2 million years ago, they were suddenly captured by some blood-red beings, who turn out to be 19th century British redcoat soldiers.
>
> In the year 2037, the still-turbulent North West Frontier province of Pakistan **near Afghanistan** is being patrolled by UN peacekeepers. A helicopter, known as Little Bird, crewed by an American pilot, Chief Warrant Officer Casey Othic, a British observer, Lieutenant Bisesa Dutt, and back-up pilot Chief Warrant Officer Abdikadir Omar, an blond, blue-eyed Afghan who claims descent from the Macedonians who conquered the area in ancient times, is badly damaged by an RPG-wielding villager. Forced to ditch, the crew are met by soldiers based at nearby Jamrud fortress, which houses a garrison of British troops from northern India, part of the British Empire. The soldiers believe the year is 1885.
>
> Casey is injured but Bisesa and Abdikadir are relatively uninjured and all three survivors are escorted to the fort to meet the commander, Captain Grove. Bisesa and Abdikadir explain to an initially unbelieving Grove what happened to them. **Both parties eventually realise and accept the fact that they are from different periods. Both parties lost all communications before the crash and they hypothesise that it coincided with the "time-slip".**
>
> Also at the fort are American reporter Josh White and **a British writer known as Ruddy – the young and still-unknown Rudyard Kipling.** The British soldiers are outnumbered by sepoys and Gurkhas.
>
> [...]
>
> Ruddy attempts to stop her and is shot fatally at the thigh. Bisesa then confronts Sable and manages to incapacitate her. She then **tells the dying Ruddy of the future that was taken away from him** by the Discontinuity.

Comment: That is it!  Thanks.